# Cannot determine why output is wrong while rotating vector

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have written the following code -

```
#include <cassert>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

vector<int> v;

int main()
{
    int n, d, i = 0;
    cin >> n >> d;
    assert(n >= 1 && n <= 100000 && d >= 1 && d <= n);
    int temp = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cin >> temp;
        v.push_back(temp);
    }
    reverse(v.begin(), v.begin() + d - 1);
    reverse(v.begin() + d, v.end());
    reverse(v.begin(), v.end());
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cout << v[i] << " ";
    return 0;
}
```

Now, the problem is that when I enter the following input -

`5 4
1 2 3 4 5`

it doesn't give me the correct output `5 1 2 3 4` but rather gives me this `5 4 1 2 3`

Any idea what might be wrong?

Comment: Did you try using a debugger?

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius - Unfortunately, this is a new system and I don't have debugging tools setup. Plus it is Linux :(

Comment: So? [There are plenty of debuggers for Linux.](http://www.drdobbs.com/testing/13-linux-debuggers-for-c-reviewed/240156817) Installing one from your Linux distro's package manager should take way less than 5 minutes. (And you probably even have at least the basic command-line version of [GDB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Debugger) installed already, even if using it without a graphical front-end does take a bit of learning.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output of the program is correct, for that input.   It is your expectations that are incorrect.

The thing to realise is that standard algorithms do not dereference specified end iterators.   So `reverse(v.begin(), v.begin() + 3)` will reverse the first three elements of `v` (i.e. `v[0]` through to `v[2]`) not the first four.

So the first `reverse()` reverses the first three elements, producing the order `3 2 1 4 5`.

To get the results you expect, it would be reversing the first four.

Comment: Thanks a lot Peter. Could you please explain this line - "The thing to realise is that standard algorithms do not dereference specified end iterators."

Comment: It means that the value corresponding to the end iterator is never accessed.